# Fixed header overlapping by content

Tags: html, css

I created a simple page. I want to have a fixed header but the content is overlapping header. I tried to use z-index and other solutions from stackoverflow but nothing is working. When I scroll down "test" paragraphs are overlapping on header.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 100%;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  min-height: 60px;
  max-height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e2eaf3;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    <h2>App</h2>
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
  </header>
  <nav class="mobile-nav">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Test</p><br>
    <p>Test</p><br>
    <p>Test</p><br>
    <p>Test</p><br>
    <p>Test</p><br>
    <p>Test</p><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just give a background color to your header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it *overlaps* is because you have no background color applied to your header, making it transparent to any overlapping content. All you'll need to do is to apply a `background-color` to fix this:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 100%;
}

header {
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  min-height: 60px;
  max-height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e2eaf3;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    <h2>App</h2>
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
  </header>
  <nav class="mobile-nav">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Test</p><br>
    <p>Test</p><br>
    <p>Test</p><br>
    <p>Test</p><br>
    <p>Test</p><br>
    <p>Test</p><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Padding-top inside body is not working, i will try to find a tutorial how to make sticky header

Comment: Ah I see the problem now. See my updated answer to see if that helps.

Comment: Holy, background-color is missing! I totally forgot about that and I was wondering why content overlaps header. Thank you so much!

Comment: Anytime! Don't forget to mark this answer as correct when you're able to.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a background to your header.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 100%;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  background:#fff;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  min-height: 60px;
  max-height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e2eaf3;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    <h2>App</h2>
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
  </header>
  <nav class="mobile-nav">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Test</p><br>
    <p>Test</p><br>
    <p>Test</p><br>
    <p>Test</p><br>
    <p>Test</p><br>
    <p>Test</p><br>
  </div>
</div>
```